# Yii - How To Show Data From Another Table in DetailView

Tags: php, yii

I am working on a project. I want to show data from another table in detailview.
So far I tried to code like below.

actionView in QController:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $allt=new A;
    $allt->unsetAttributes();
    $allt->id_q=$id;

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        'allt'=>$allt,
    ));
}
```

Then, detailview in views/q/view.php

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',array(
        'data'=>$allt,
        'attributes'=>array(
        'id_a', //primary key from tbl_q
        'id_q', //foreign key from tbl_q
        array(
            'name'=>'optionA',
            'label'=>'Option A',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>CHtml::encode(A::model()->findByPk($allt->id_a)->optionA), //this I've tried, but throws error: Trying to get property of non-object
        ),
        'optionC',
        'optionD',
        'optionE',
    ),
)); ?>
```

In that example, I want to show `optionA`  but it throws error: Trying to get property of non-object.

FYI, when I tried to show it from CGridView, it worked great with code similar above.

I hope you can help me to solve this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you just defined the `id_q` attribute of `$allt`;

So when you are going to perform `A::model()->findByPk($allt->id_a)` this will return `null` because `$allt->id_a` is null and the record won't be found.

Then you are trying to call `->optionA` on the result of the `findByPk` method but since it's null there is no object here. This is why you have the following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object.

By the way it is a very bad practice to perform some DB call in the view.

Comment: I just a noob. But, I have my problem solved by now. Thanks. I appreciate your answer and show my mistakes

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to mark the answer as resolving your problem if it does!